# Check synthesis output online?

Tags: verilog, synthesis, vlsi

Is there any tool/application available online which helps me to check the synthesis output of the RTL written?

Example: I have written some RTL code(In verilog) and want to check

-> If it is synthesize-able or not?

-> Netlist RTL has generated.

Comment: yosys, of course.

Comment: [EDAplaygound](https://edaplaygound.com) has online synthesizer and simulator options.

Answer (score 0):

Might this meet your needs?

http://www.plunify.com/

Some words from the website to make this answer long enough...

> Plunify helps design teams manage and scale compute demands, providing
>   FPGA synthesis and place-and-route on a pay-as-you-use basis